# Soot - How to prevent loadClassAndSupport to create an empty SootClass?

Tags: java, soot

Using the soot framework (v.2.5.0) I'm trying to load a certain class:

```
SootClass clazz = Scene.v().loadClassAndSupport("example.MyClass");
```

Before calling `Scene#loadClassAndSupport` the class `example.MyClass` is NOT within the scene - which is correct.
The class also doesn't exist on the soot classpath and there the statement above throws a `RuntimeException` telling that the class could not be found. And that's also correct behaviour.

But after that exception has been thrown the class `example.MyClass` is within soot's scene!
Another call to `Scene#loadClassAndSupport` therefore returns a `SootClass` instance where `isPhantom` is set to false but it doesn't have any methods or fields.

1. *Is this behaviour intended by the soot framework or is it a bug?*
2. *If it is intended, how can I prevent Soot from adding a "dummy" SootClass to the scene?*
3. *Is there another way to test whether a certain class is within Soot's classpath without adding it to Soot's scene?*

**Update:**
An ugly but working workaround is:

```
try {
  SootClass sootClass = Scene.v().loadClassAndSupport( className );
  sootClass.setApplicationClass();
  // class found and loaded...
} catch(RuntimeException e) {
  SootClass sootClass = Scene.v().loadClassAndSupport( className );
  Scene.v().removeClass( sootClass );
  // class not on soot's classpath or not loadable...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug. Can you please file it here? We will then take a look.
https://github.com/Sable/soot/issues

This is the better place to discuss such issues anyway.

Cheers,
Eric